# Macroeconomics- money supply LM model

Tags: macroeconomics, keynesian-economics

why does an increase in money supply , lower the interest rate and shift the LM curve down.?

Comment: This is college economics , you can discuss the advanced stuff in your head buddy. Vote off !

Answer (score 3):

In the standard LM Model money supply is a vertical line and money demand is a decreasing function (in the interest rate - money framework). An increase in the money supply curve shifts the supply curve to the right which ceteris paribus decreases the intersect with the demand curve which leads to a lower interest rate.